# Zip code field in form not displaying results

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have form that that displays data based on city and zip code. It was working fine and users are able to receive the results.

However, the zip code field is no longer working and I am not sure why. Based on what I can see, it passing two possible outcomes. "0" if the zip code is valid and "1" if the zip code is not. For some reason, it is passing both values and by default, it will show the error message that the zip code is not valid.

I am not sure how to fix the issue. I have posted what I did and based on what I see, I do not see why the zip by default display the error. I have another form and its the exact same code and it works fine.

```js
(
function(){
 var $scope, $location;
 var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
 
 indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
  $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
  $scope.ShowResults = false;
  $scope.ShowDesc = true;
  $scope.NoResults = false;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
  $scope.formModel = {};
  $scope.searchMode = 0;
  $scope.miles = [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
  $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
  $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
  $scope.Languages = {};
  $scope.Cities = {};
  $scope.searchParam = {};
  $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
  
  $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];
  
  $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
   try{
    var lon, lat;
    // console.log('starting geoposition code.');
    if("geolocation" in navigator){
     window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
      lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
      lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
      // console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
      $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
      .then(function(response){
       $scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;
      })
     })
    }
    else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
   }
   catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
  }
  
  $scope.GetCityList = function (){
   try{
    $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnCityList.cfm")
     .then(function(response){
      $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
     })
   }
   catch(err){}
  }
  
  $scope.GetLangList = function (){
   try{
   $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnLangList.cfm")
     .then(function(response){
      $scope.Languages = response.data.Languages;
     })
   }
   catch(err){}
  }
  
  $scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam){
   try{
    $scope.searchMode = 1;
    var queryString='';
    if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
     $scope.resultsCount = 0;
     currentPage = 1;
    }
    if(searchParam){
     $scope.formModel = searchParam;
     for(var param in searchParam){
      if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
       var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
       if (paramValue.length > 0)
        queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
      }
     }
    }
    console.log(queryString);
    queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;
    
    $http.get("/includes/remote/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
    .then(function(response){
     $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
     $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
     if (!$scope.providers){
       $scope.NoResults = true;
       $scope.ShowResults = false;
       $scope.ShowDesc = false;
      }
     else{
       $scope.NoResults = false;
       $scope.ShowResults = true;
       $scope.ShowDesc = false;
      }
    })
   }
   catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
  }
  
  $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
   try{
    if($scope.searchMode == 1){
     $scope.SearchProvider($scope.formModel);
     }
   }
   catch(err){}
  });
  

  $scope.GetCityList();
  $scope.GetLangList();
  $scope.GetCurrentZip();
  
  $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
   //http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/
     // set the location.hash to the id of
     // the element you wish to scroll to.
     
   //$location.hash('bottom');
   
     // call $anchorScroll()
   var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
   if (browserWidth < 768)
    anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
  };
 
 });
 
 indexApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
  this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

   // This scrolling function 
   // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript
   
   var startY = currentYPosition();
   var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
   var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
   if (distance < 100) {
    scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
   }
   var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
   if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
   var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
   var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
   var timer = 0;
   if (stopY > startY) {
    for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
     setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
     leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
    } return;
   }
   for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
    leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
   }
   
   function currentYPosition() {
    // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
    // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
     return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
    if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
    return 0;
   }
   
   function elmYPosition(eID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
    var y = elm.offsetTop;
    var node = elm;
    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
     node = node.offsetParent;
     y += node.offsetTop;
    } return y;
   }

  };
  
 });
 
 indexApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
 indexApp.directive('popPopup',[describePopup]);
 indexApp.directive('pop', function pop ($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {      
      var first = true;
      attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
        if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
   $timeout(function(){
    element.triggerHandler('event');
   });
   }
   first = false;
  });
  return compile(element, attrs);
  };
  return tooltip;
 });
 
 indexApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
 return function(phoneNumber){
  var dash = '-';
  var openParen = '(';
  var closeParen = ') ';
  if(phoneNumber){
   var pn = phoneNumber;
   pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
   pn = openParen + [pn.slice(0, 3), closeParen, pn.slice(3)].join('');
   return pn;
   }
  return phoneNumber;
  }
 });
 
 indexApp.filter('Zip', function(){
 return function(zipcode){
  var dash = '-';
  if(zipcode && zipcode.length > 5){
   var zc = zipcode;
   zc = [zc.slice(0, 5), dash, zc.slice(5)].join('');
   return zc;
   }
  return zipcode;
  }
 });
 
 function allowPatternDirective(){
  return{
   restrict: "A",
   compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
     element.bind("keypress", function(event){
      var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
      var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
      
      if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
      }
     });
    }
   }
  }
 }

 function describePopup(){
  return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   replace: true,
   scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
   templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
   };
  }
})();
(function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
       var $target = label.data('target');
       if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<cfset name_list1 = "Family Practice,General Practice,Internal Medicine,Pediatrics">    
<cfset name_list2 = "RMG,MG,R">    
<cfquery name="cityFind datasource="Wea">
 SELECT DISTINCT city FROM providerWeb_Multiple WITH(NOLOCK) 
 where ProviderSpecialty in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list1#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">) 
 and Company_ID in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list2#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)  
    order by city
</cfquery>

   <cfquery name="Languages" datasource="Webpagea">
            select DISTINCT language from Provider_Lang
            order by language  
    </cfquery>
   

<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
            <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

   <div class="form-group">
             <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
        <option value=""></option>
        <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                           <option value=#trim(city)#>#trim(city)#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
            <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>--->
            </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
     <div class="form-group widthLanguage">
              
                      
                    <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
      <cfoutput query="Languages">
        <option value=#language#>#language#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
                      
                      
       <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
         <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
          </select>--->
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
     <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
    </div>
   </div>
            
            <hr class="hrDoctor" />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>
            
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"><option selected="selected" value=" "><option selected="selected">5</option><option selected="selected">10</option><option selected="selected">15</option><option selected="selected">20</option> </select>

       <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
     <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group"><input id ="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question would get read by more people if you got rid of the irrelevent code.  All that stuff about genders is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using CFML the easiest way to test for a good zip, even before it's sent, is to use cfinput validation. Also keep in mind `nnnnn-nnnn` is a valid US zip.

```
<cfinput 
id="zip" name="zipcode" maxlength="10" 
type="number" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Zip code" 
pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" 
validate="zipcode" 
message="Enter a valid zipcode" 
ng-model="searchParam.Zip"  />
```

Comment: I had no idea that "nnnn-nnnn" is a valid zip code, thank you for that. The problem is I have another form that uses the exact same code and yet it works. The error does display if the zip code is not valid but for the other form, it just displays the error. If I would try your approach, where would it go?

Comment: @ Jules. I have tried your approach and still displays the error notifying the user that zip code is not valid

Comment: @ Jules: Is it the js file that I created to read the zip code and then pass it to get the results from the database? If so, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You would remove your JS based zipcode test and let CF do it for you. Replace `<input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />` with `<cfinput 
id="zip" name="zipcode" maxlength="10" 
type="number" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Zip code" 
pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" 
validate="zipcode" 
message="Enter a valid zipcode" 
ng-model="searchParam.Zip"  />`